# Can't make a div float right (may be because of flexbox?)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically, got a container div in the middle of the page and 2 children divs. Need the right one to be at the very right of container. Float:right doesn't work. Can't use margin-left since i want it to work with any resolution. Right:0 doesn't work as well. Using flexbox. May be it has something to do with it.

html code

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child1">adsfasdfdsa</div>
 <div class="child2">192837192</div>
</div>
```

css code

```
.parent {
  -o-display:flex;
  -webkit-display:flex;
  -ms-display:flex;
  -moz-display:flex;
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:flex; 
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.child2 {float:right;}
```

here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/82yXE/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `position:absolute;` and `right:11%`

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tsHunter/82yXE/3/) is what it looks like.

Comment: Why haven't i thought of that -facepalm-. Thanks!

Comment: something cancels that margin, but i'll figure it out

Comment: If you need more help let me know. Otherwise feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you. Good luck!

Comment: it's all working. Been waiting for the time to accept answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh I didn't even know there was a time limit haha. Sorry! Cheers! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the left margin to `auto`, it will force the browser moving `.child2` to the right position:

```
.child2 {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Check this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/e6eLf8yu/

Comment: Could you be more specific as to the issue you have with my answer?

Comment: exactly! I did the reply in the same way as you did :) Your answer was marked for deletion by someone, because of the contents and lengths. Can you be more explicit and specific with you answer? - so it actually helps to troubleshoot and explains what was made wrong in the relation to the question.

Comment: Well you see, the OP wants the child div at the right of the container, he used `float:right;` as he mentioned which didn't work. I suggested `margin-left:auto;' to achieve the desired result. There's nothing more to it. Why would I write 1000 words for that?

Comment: VeeK, I did it for you. No need in 1000 words, but the answer has to contain explicit information, and to be short, according to the best practices of StackOverflow... get the up-vote from me.

Comment: I see. Well thanks for showing me. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example. For better results I will add a clearfix css div.

```css
.parent {
  -o-display:flex;
  -webkit-display:flex;
  -ms-display:flex;
  -moz-display:flex;
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:flex; 
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
    background-color:white;
  }
.child1, .child2 {
  float: left;
  width:50%
  }
.child2{
  text-align: right;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child1">adsfasdfdsa</div>
 <div class="child2">192837192</div>
</div>
```